# Can I use regex to look for strings in a big file that meet the following conditions:

Tags: regex

**EDITED FOR CLARIFICATION & SPECIFICITY**

I know this is a tough one, but I thought I'd ask anyway...

I'm using grep or egrep  "grep-E" (with extended regex capability). I was also told that Strings could be used and may help with this effort, but I haven't fully explored that option yet...

**Input file:** is a binary file so it contains all kind of junk

**Desired Output:** strings that meet all of these conditions:

1. Return ONLY strings with (8-24 readable characters), exclude white spaces " ", as they are are delimiters (separators) of strings in the input file.
2. ONLY the following characters can makeup a string and are allowed ANYWHERE (beginning, end, middle) in a string:

"0-9" "a-z" "A-Z" ! # $ % ^ & ( ) @ ~ " ' ] ? [ * + ; ,  =

1. The following characters are **NOT** allowed in a stream:

/ \ . | : < > ***except the dot '.' it can ONLY be at the beginning or at the end of the string, but NOT in the middle.*** BUT I have removed it completely form the regex, b/c I don't know the syntax of specifying taht it can only be at the end or beginning of a stream. and if I include the dot in the dot, it returns tons of "false strings" "junk"

1. No stream should contain 3 or more repeated back-to-back characters i.e strings that have 3 or more repeated (back2back) chars should be ignored

i.e. aaab^s zY&$$$$[[[[[[777th, or ((((%%*_*+++------ should be ignored.

1. All non-readable characters should be ignored is acceptable in a stream.

i.e. subscripts ¹q n× ÷ ± Ð à ÿÿ Û è á » Ù ˆ © ò etc...

I've tested some of your suggestions and so far, this regex does about 90% of the job.

**(?!(.)\1{3})[0-9a-zA-Z!#$%^&()@~"'*-+][;,=]{8,24}**

but only when tested on dubdubdubrubular.com or dubdubdub.gethifi.com/tools/regex For some reason, grep is chocking on it!!!

for your reference, I'm including a sample of the binary file in question:

Sample:

http://pastebin.com/wY6a0Uir

Note: if you test the sample on http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex you'll see that returned line #21 for example should not have been returned.

Hope this clarifies the question a bit, and not confuse it more :)

Cheers!

Comment: You don't show an example of more than 4 repeated characters. And for grins, please explain what `excluding dots and whitespaces` mean. Literally its `[^.\s]`

Comment: Foremost, you must explain more explicitly what the Set of characters 6-24 that you are looking for, because that fixes your second problem right away.

Comment: You're correct! I didn't show more than 4 chars, I also didn't show one for less than 4 chars :). As for dots and white spaces, those are undesired chars and are actually delimiters (separators) of strings. for example, q^Yhj%p7 meets the 2 conditions, but q^Y.hj%p7 or q^Yhj %p7 don't b/c they contain "." and " ". Any set of characters on a standard keyboard are acceptable except "." and " " Here I tried to capture all of them, but I think I may have missed a couple '[' and ']' and & Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to reverse engineer with that file?

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports it, you can use a zero-width negative lookahead assertion with a back reference. Add this to the beginning of your regex:

```
(?!(.)\1{3})
```

So the full regex looks like this:

```
(?!(.)\1{3})[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%\^()+_{}]{6,24}
```

Or this:

```
(?!(.)\1{3})[!--/-\~]{6,24}
```

Test it at:

http://rubular.com/r/RbYIXR4a16

Comment: If whitespace is the "delimiter" between the strings you are looking for, you could add ``(?:^|\s+)`` (beginning of string or whitespace) to the start and ``(?:$|\s+)`` (end of string or whitespace) to the end.

Comment: Wow! Pretty darn close! See test results http://imageshack.us/a/img201/6410/7ho1.png It's returning that long stream ((((%%%%%%%% and it shouldn't. Also you've made me aware of yet a few exception: The stream cannot have ',' ';' ':' '-' or '_' except at the end of beginning of the stream! If this last condition is too difficult, which I know it probably is, then please ignore "except at the end of beginning of the stream" Thank You! –

Comment: I don't think Poster realize what they say when saying NOT x-amout of repeating characters. Either the entire group of repeaters has to be excluded, or use the same repeaters as valid by advancing the search position by 1, until its < 4. Your regex will match aaaaa`aaa8bheexs`  but maybe thats what the OP needs, who knows.

Comment: What breaks a string is not only a while space, but also a dot, a comma, a semi-colon, a colon, a hyphen, an underscore, or this char '|', except, if they're at the beginning or at the end of a string.

Comment: @sln, Maybe I'm not following you, so I'm not sure what you mean. If a string has 4 or more repeated chars in it, don't return it.

Comment: And another mention, this part of your code `[class]{6,24}` will contain repeaters. Where's the check for them there?

Comment: @user2957951 - Is that a question?

Comment: No it's not. its a desired output. So far, the closest I have is this: (?:$|\s+)(?!(.)\1{3})[!--/-\~]{6,24}(?:^|\s+) BUT it still returning text that contains , ; : _ - | when it should be excluded. Thank you again for trying to help me. I think we're pretty close :) How do I exclude those chars? Cheers!

Comment: I think it's the wrong way around. ``^`` goes at the beginning and ``$`` at the end.

Comment: @user2957951 - Your desired output has many facets. It can be broken down into 2 requirements, a class of desired characters and a serialization restriction. This is going to be hard to do in a single regex. But, you can split twice to get what you need, or you can let the engine trod along in an imposible assertion nightmare. Serialization can go different ways. Regex engines position is always between a character. That means you can define serialization in both directions. And acfrancis regex as I said, fails a repeat check at the end. Good Luck to you

Comment: @acfrancis: ok fixed Thank You! Now how do I exclude the following chars form a string , ; : " - _ / \ | except if it's at the end or beginning of a given string? Thanks Again!

Comment: @sln: Thank you. I will definitely pursue that avenue if the 1-regex solution doesn't work, but I think this is doing the job "(?:^|\s+)(?!(.)\1{3})[!--/-\~]{6,24}(?:$|\s+)", we just need add a few char exceptions (see my previous post. Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, I've lost track of what you are asking for. It sounds like you are happy with everything but the middle part of the regex and you've left conflicting comments about what that part should match (which chars are allowed at the beginning of the string, for example). Please update the question with your exact requirements if you want more help with the regex.

Comment: You're correct! Frankly, I didn't know what I was getting myself into :) I was over-simplifying the problem in my head :( I will update the question and try to capture all requirements. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say your best shot is to split the string on `[^[:cntrl:].\ ]\1{4,}`
Then split again each element on `[[:cntrl:].\ ]`

Otherwise you're in an eternal lookbehind/ahead nightmare.

Comment: You mean split the file? I cannot do that. I just need a regex that works in grep or egrep. this expression [^[:cntrl:].\ ]\1{4,} does not work in http://rubular.com/r/lpURANM3n1.