# Regex that does excludes characters that repeat (3) three or more times

Tags: regex, repeat

I'm looking for a regex that searches a file and does NOT return (i.e. it excludes) chars that repeat 3 or more times consecutively in a string. I've tried this expression below, but it's NOT doing the the job :( ..something that looks fwd and backward and excludes strings that have 3 or more repeating back-to back chars. i.e. it should return `abcdefg`, but not `3333ahg` or `gagjjjjagy` or `hdajgjga111`

```
(?!(.)\1{3})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using following regex to match string containing 3 or more repeating back-to-back characters

```
(.)\1{2,}
```

And then invert the match using flags. Most of the languages support it.

For example, with `grep`

```
$ cat file
abcdefg
gagjagyyy
3333ahg

$ grep -v -E '(.)\1{2,}' file
abcdefg
```

Comment: Thank you...it's pretty close, but it returns only the repeated pattern. We should actually NEGATE that expression, b/c I need exactly the opposite. I want to capture those strings that Don't have 3 + repeated back-to-back characters...use http://rubular.com/r/lpURANM3n1 and try this as a test, note that strings are separated by " " white spaces: text1 114444 text2 texxxt3 114444text4 text5 .Regex should only return text1 text2 and text5

Comment: @user2957951 Did you read my answer carefully? `And then invert the match using flags.`. Please observe `-v` option of `grep`. It does *NEGATE* that regex. Did you try running that command? Sorry to say but it doesn't make sense (to me at-least) to NEGATE easier regex and make it more complicated rather than just using right tool with right option with proper regex.

Comment: Thanks jkshah, but when i try your expression -v -E '(.)\1{2,}' in rubular it says no match! Sorry, but this is just one piece of the puzzle, maybe that's why it's not making sense to you. Eventually I need to AND your expression with this: (?:^|\s+)[0-9a-zA-Z!"#$%&'()*+]{8,24} on this testfile: http://ge.tt/4rum8Iz/v/0?c HERE is my end-goal. Maybe you could help with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897246/can-i-use-regex-to-look-for-strings-in-a-big-file-that-meet-the-following-condit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1\1.*$).+$ - matches whole string as one word

(?=\b|^)(?!\w*(\w)\1\1\w*)\w+(?:\b|$) - matches one word
```

Example: http://rubular.com/r/dkIHkDo67g

Comment: It is working as far I can see. It matches string which doesn't contain 3 repeating chars and matches one that doesn't. This was your expetation, or at least I understood it that way.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that whole string should be matched as one being. I made update in which words within strings are matched. Example: http://rubular.com/r/9DDh92fovb

Comment: Still not working Lolo! please(see test) http://rubular.com/r/kDR6HZH1Nt and it looks like it's ignoring chars like ! and %  etc... please see my las response to jkshah, that;s really what I'm trying to... Thanks!

Comment: There was still one extra `$` in regex. Now it is better: http://rubular.com/r/dkIHkDo67g
Non-word chars are indeed ignored, because I used \w to match word and \b to match word boundary. You can adjust that by changing chars classes

Comment: Thanks Lolo, any idea why your expression is not working in http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex?!! also in rubular, it look like it's only returning "blanks" 1. blank 2. blank etc... Also you've made an assumption that strings only contain words. No strings can also contain these characters !@#$%^()&<>[]/-_.,;=:|+? and we should also exclude these chars (if they're 3 or more back to back). Basically any character you can type on a standard keyboard, can make up a stream, and we should exclude them if they repeat 3 or more time back to back in any stream. Thanks

Comment: WHITE SPACES SHOULD BE EXCLUDED (SHOULD NOT BE RETURNED), BECAUSE THEY SEPARATE STRINGS Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, you may try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    const string
        isMatch = "IsMatch",
        pattern = @"(?:(?<Open>\w*?(\w)\1{{2,}}\w*)|(?<{0}>\w*))";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
        var regex = String.Format(pattern, isMatch);
        var matches = Regex.Matches(input, regex)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select<Match, Group>(m => m.Groups[isMatch])
            .Where(g => g.Value != string.Empty)
            .ToList();

        matches.ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(m.Value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I need a regex. I don't know C :(